# About drawing dots using react-native-signature-capture

Tags: react-native, npm, digital-signature

I'm using this lib: https://github.com/RepairShopr/react-native-signature-capture and I need to draw dots on it. The problem is that the drawing itself just appears if I move my finger a little bit, what result in a slightly line, not a dot. So what do I need to change for the dots to appear when I touch the screen?

Comment: same problem, did you find any solution bro?

Comment: Facing same issue, did you get any solution ?